# Union of non-intersecting finite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $|A|=k$ and $|C|=n$, finite cardinalities, and $A\cap C= \varnothing$. What is $|A\cup C|$? Prove your answer.

I have done problems similar before, but none with finite cardinalities, so I'm not sure what the union is.

Comment: The union is what it always is: the set of things that are in at least one of the sets $A$ and $C$. If $A$ and $C$ have no elements in common, how many things is that?

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of [cardinal sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_addition)? (A bit overkill here, but may be helpful depending on your background.)

Comment: |A u C| = n + k? I'm not sure how to prove that

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using analysis. Considering the bijections $f : I_k \to A$ and $g : I_n \to C$ where $I_k = \{p \in \mathbb N ; p \leq k\}$, analogously  $I_n = \{p \in \mathbb N; p\leq n\}$ and  $A \cap C = \emptyset$.

Then take the function $h: I_{k+n} \to A \cup C$ defined by

$$\begin{align}h(x) =\begin{cases} f(x) &, \text{if}\ \  0\leq x \leq k\\ g(x-k)&, \text{if}\ \   1 + k \leq x \leq n+k\end{cases} \end{align}$$

Show that this is a bijection, then you'll have

$$|A \cup C| = \color{#05f}{k+ n} = |A| + |C|$$

Comment: I don't think "using the integers" constitutes analysis here; I don't think there is a rigorous proof that doesn't involve $\Bbb N$ in some way, since "finite" is defined in terms of it and the answer $k+n$ doesn't make sense without it.

Comment: Sure, I understand, I just don't know the context here, so I pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Since both $A$ and $C$ are finite, let $A = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$ and $C = \{c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_k\}$. Thus, $\mid A \cup C\mid$ is at most $n + k$. Is there any way it could be strictly less than $\mid A \cup C\mid$, given that $A \cap C = \emptyset$?